# Demodulating a signal generated by IR LED/ phototransistor pair

Tags: led, transistors, demodulation

I am driving an IR LED with a 20kHz square-wave signal (I may/ may not use PWM) and I am trying to demodulate the signal being generated by the corresponding phototransistor. I don't have access to demodulator ICs so that means I have to build a demodulator using an op-amp. My current plan is to subtract the original square-wave signal from the IR LED modulated square-wave signal using a difference amplifier built from an op-amp. My question is this: Is a difference amplifier a sufficient solution to my problem, or is there a better option out there? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the signal you are trying to demodulate?  Is it simply the presence or absence of the 20 kHz carrier or something else?  If you can use around 40 kHz there are off the shelf modules that do just that.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - I am trying to demodulate the signal that is produced when a finger is placed between the IR LED and the phototransitor. This link shows an example of the signal that I am trying to extract(http://bsamig.uku.fi/research/bloodpress.shtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done exactly what you are trying to do (for photoplethysmography). The demodulation is easily done with a [sample-and-hold type circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_and_hold).

To see why, just think about how the blood modulates the pulses of the carrier signal. It effectively scales the amplitude of the pulses (hence it is amplitude modulation) according to the heart beat waveform. Then the S/H circuit samples the amplitude of each pulse, recovering the heart waveform itself.

[image: Working version of the circuit from_http://www.electronics-circuits.com/schematics/analog_circuits/del10011.png]

[Here's a working implementation of the circuit.](http://schematics.dapj.com/2005/01/simple-sample-and-hold.html) You simply close the switch for a period when the IR LED is on, then keep it open and it will hold the value sampled until the next IR LED pulse.

Comment: What about the effect of noise? Do I place a low-pass filter before the sample and hold circuit?

Comment: Good question. Because you are sampling the signal, any noise beyond the nyquist frequency (i.e. half the sampling rate) will get aliased into the pass band (10 kHz) which means more noise in your signal. So if noise ends up being a problem, you'll want to have a LPF ahead of the S/H with as low a cut-off as you can. My guess though is that at 20 kHz sample rate it won't be much of a problem. Why? Well if you put a LPF _after_ the S/H with a cutoff of 20 Hz (for PPG), such a small portion of the aliased noise (which is spread across 10 kHz) is passed.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your problem, you want to detect whether the light path between a IR LED and IR phototransistor is interrupted or not.  You are driving the LED with a 20 kHz square wave, so want to know how to detect this coming out of the phototransistor.

My first answer is to use 35-50 kHz modulation in bursts of about 15 cycles on and off, and then use a off the shelf IR demodulator IC.  You say you don't have access to one, but that is hard to believe since you do have access to the internet.  Several companies make such things.  Vishay TSOP is one I remember off the top of my head, but I know there are others.  These are three terminal devices.  You supply power and ground, and the third pin indicates whether carrier is detected or not.  Most assume carrier comes in bursts and will eventually null out a steady carrier.  That is why I said send carrier in bursts of 15 cycles or so on and off.  The IC will then give you a square wave output with high and low periods of about 15 carrier cycles.  You detect the presence of the beam by looking for this square wave output.  It can be as simple as requiring a particular edge within 1 or 2 ms.  The reason for switching to 35-50 kHz carrier is because these ICs come in fixed frequencies roughly in that range.

If you really have to do this yourself for some reason, the trick is to high pass filter such that the ambient light level is ignored.  You don't need a fancy notch filter, but a simple R-C high and low pass with rolloff at your carrier frequency should be good enough to eliminate ambient light noise.  After that you amplify and detect.  Again, the amplifier is AC coupled.

Comment: @OlinLathrop- Thanks for the recommendation of the filters, it sounds good.